# reduce time when a different cell is blank

Tags: excel, sum

I am trying to build a program in Excel where if data is entered into a cell, the time will reduce in another cell.

I have 2 columns. One currently calculates slots based on blank cells. This is working fine using COUNTBLANK.

=COUNTBLANK('E1&3'!C3:C7)+COUNTBLANK('E1&3'!C16:C44)+COUNTBLANK('E1&3'!C50:C60)+COUNTBLANK('E1&3'!C68:C70)+COUNTBLANK('E1&3'!C76:C96)+COUNTBLANK('E1&3'!C101:C102)

I have another which calculates hours available and again this is working fine using =SUM.
=SUM('E1&3'!B3:C7)

What I want to do is combine these where if a cell becomes blank the time will increase, and if not blank it will decrease and I am not sure how to do that. I know that you can not have 2 different formulas at once within a cell, so I am trying to figure out the combined formula.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score -1):

never mind, worked it out using SUMIF!

Ok so if I get a thumbs down there is a better way? interested to hear it...